# SharePoint Designer Workflow in app

Tags: office-365, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 designer workflow which I would like to add to an app.  I can find no documentation on this (how to do or even if it's possible).  Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done?

I have tried exporting it to a wsp and importing it into Visual Studio and including the features in my app (even though they are in different projects VS 2013 lets me add them to my app) but when I deploy the workflow does not appear to have been deployed.

Comment: If it is a simple workflow then probably you can convert it into a Visual Studio workflow as explained http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/03/12/creating-sharepoint-2013-workflow-apps.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out a way to do this.  Will blog about it sometime soon, but in short:

1. In SharePoint Designer, save the workflow as a template.
2. Download the template (WSP) from the Site Assets library.
3. Import the WSP into a Visual Studio project as described here:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231603.aspx
4. Add this new workflow project to the solution containing the app.
5. In the package of the app project, add the feature for the workflow so the workflow will be included in the app (because they are in the same solution Visual Studio makes features available in the other solution).
6. In the package manager in Visual Studio, click on the "Template" tab and on the bottom expand the "Edit Options" and click on "Overwrite generated XML and edit manifest in the XML editor". Click yes to confirm.
7. Click the link to edit in the XML editor.
8. Remove the  block from the template.  This DLL is actually not needed and does not contain anything, but it will prevent you from deploying to Office 365.
9. When you deploy the app you will now have your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do anything with SPD in a SharePoint app.  You need to create the workflow in Visual Studio and bind it to the list there.

To create the workflow using SP designer you need to open the App web using SharePoint designer, but this still not supported (you cannot open the app web site from SPD) so you cannot create the workflows in APps using SPD.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/761a7cd3-35b9-4d69-9847-7e90b5e27863/sharepoint-designer-workflow-in-app?forum=appsforsharepoint